# Automating NodeJS application using Lambda (json file is created)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want my application to be able to run automatically, every hour of every day. The NodeJS script produces a JSON file, which needs to be uploaded to an EC2 instance. As the question notes, I am planning on making this happen using Lambda, and `cron` jobs. I know how to schedule it, but I don't know if

a. I can create a file using Lambda functions

b. Even if I can, will I be able to move the file from Lambda to my instance?

Do I need to use S3 buckets?

Answer (score 1):

There are few possibilities of doing this. I will list one which, in my view, is most scalable (can work with multiple instance) and manageable.

The use case could work in the following way:

1. Schedule your lambda function to be triggered automatically using **CloudWatch Events** and cron expressions.
2. Have the lambda function create the required file and upload it to **S3**.
3. Use the same lambda to trigger **SSM Run Command** which is going to run a code on your instance(s). The code will download the file from S3.
4. Can also setup **notification** for the SSM Run Command, to be notified when  it finishes successfully or fail, using CloudWatch Events.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem I was having was that, my node application would stop running if I exited the terminal (via Putty). So, now I'm going to use `nohup` and `node-schedule`.